# Print and save data in binary format in Perl

Tags: perl

My script generates some very very huge files, and I am trying to print/save the output in a binary format to reduce the file size as much as possible!

Each time that script generates five values, like:

```
$a1 = 1.64729
$a2 = 4.33329
$a3 = 3.55724
$a4 = 1.45759
$a5 = 7.474700
```

It prints in the output like:

```
A:1.64729,4.33329,3.55724,1.45759,7.474700
```

I am not sure whether this is the best way, but I thought to pack each row when it is printing to the output! I used pack/unpack built-in function in Perl!

I had a look at perldoc, but I did not understand which format specifiers were proper (???)!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

...

@A = ($a1,$a2,$a3,$a4,$a5);

print pack ("???", ("A:", join(",", map { sprintf "%.1f", $_ } @A)), "\n";
```

Comment: you are probably better off just using compression on the whole file.  you can compress it while you write it and uncompress it while you read it if necessary.  just how big is "very very huge"?

Comment: 1000 files, each compressed file 1.7 G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compress the file (instead of trying to write binary bytes) you will get a small file. That's because your entire file will have mostly the ten digit characters, plus a decimal point, and a comma.

You can compress a file as you write it via [IO::Zlib](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Zlib.html). This will use either the Zlib library, or the `gzip` command.

However, if you want to use `pack`, go ahead. Get the [Camel Book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do) which gives much clearer documentation than the standard Perldoc.

It's not all that difficult:

```
my $output = "A:1.64729,4.33329,3.55724,1.45759,7.474700";
$output =~ s/^A://;                  #Remove the 'A:'
my @numbers = split /,/, $output     # Make into an array
my $packed =  pack "d5", @numbers;   # Pack five inputs as floating point numbers
say join ",", "d5", $packed;         # Unpacks those five decimal encoded numbers
```

You'll probably have to use `syswrite` and `sysread` since aren't reading and writing strings. This is unbuffered reading and writing, and you have to specify the number of bytes you're reading or writing.

One more thing: If you know where the decimal point is in the number (that is, it's always a number between 1 and up to 10) you can convert the number into an integer which will allow you to *pack* the number into an even smaller number of bytes:

```
my $output = "A:1.64729,4.33329,3.55724,1.45759,7.474700";
$output =~ s/^A://;                  #Remove the 'A:'
$output =~ s/,//g;                   #Remove all the decimal points
my @numbers = split /,/, $output     # Make into an array
my $packed =  pack "L5", @numbers;   # Pack five inputs as unsigned long numbers
```